# mail composer view controller keyboard over keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using `MFMailComposerViewController` in my iphone application (**ios 6** deployment target).

When i am entering a invalid address and clicking on send, it some times showing strange keyboard over keyboard.

Please see attached image.

has anyone else having experience same issue?

[image]

I can share code if its significant here.

Thank you ..

Comment: did you use layer in this claas ?

Comment: @mindfreak no layer, simply opening MFMailComposeViewController.And this bug doesn't come every time i am not able to reproduce it, but after passing through this view controller in navigation hierarchy/flow it happening some time.

Comment: Seems like a bug in MFMailComposeViewController. Have you raised a radar?